# Transactions with WCF DataService and DataServiceContext around multiple additions/updates

Tags: wcf, rest, transactions, odata

I have a WCF service that exposes a database using System.Data.Services.DataService and a generated client proxy that consumes this service using a System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.

What I need to be able to do is make multiple additions/changes to the DataServiceContext on the client side but have these changes performed as a single transaction.

I thought of the following possibilities for accomplishing this but am unsure if these would be correct or not:

1. Delay calling SaveChanges() until all the required additions/modifications have been made and are successful. If any of the operations fails, somehow undo all the changes made so far so that the next time SaveChanges() is called, none of modifications will be sent to the server. (I'm not sure if even on the client side everything was successful before calling SaveChanges() if something goes wrong on the server side the server will treat a single SaveChanges() call as a transaction since it actually sends a separate POST request for each modification)
2. Use batch updates (I'm not sure if the server can or will handle the multiple operations within a single batch update request as a single transaction or not)
3. Somehow use TransactionScope (still not sure if doing this I would be able to call SaveChanges() after each update and the whole set of operations would be treated as a single transaction because they were all in the scope of the TransactionScope or if I would need to call SaveChanges() only once when done, which is basically the same situation as 1. but with the addition of the TransactionScope)

I have seen other questions similar to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17597290/what-strategies-exist-to-accomplish-transactions-over-an-odata-service-layer) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346964/if-transactions-over-rest-are-unachievable-how-can-rest-ever-be-really-useful?rq=1). The second question seems to imply that this is not possible conceptually due to the nature of a RESTful service, but I am wondering if it is still possible technically using WCF specifically.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this using WCF Data Services - take a look at Batch processing: [WCF Data Services batch processing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744839%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: The documentation is not clear. On the one hand it says that the batch operation will occur atomically but then it says "When any single query operation in the batch fails, error information is returned in the QueryOperationResponse<T> object for the operation that failed and the remaining operations are still executed.". And if IS performed atomically, is the method of performing batch using SaveChanges with the batch option completely equivalent?

Comment: You should be able to use the Interceptor functions to check if operations are called after error - for exmaple if there are three POSTs in your BATCH then the change interceptor for that entity will be called three times.